# Is there way to acquire flight paths?

Tags: data, maps

I am attempting to do a project for work that requires checking general (assumed or average) flight paths (position and speed along the route) against other data. Does this exist somewhere?

Ideally there would be some database. I could build some average paths from some of the live updating sites I've seen, but I haven't found a way to actually pull off data using a program.

Flight paths in the Mediterranean specifically.

Ideally I could get something like:
{latitude, longitude, altitude, magnitude of velocity}

EDIT: I did find this (https://developer.flightstats.com/api-docs/flightstatus/v2) which looks like I could write something to potentially average out some flight paths, but if there is already something out there that exists I would much prefer to not have to do that.

Comment: Have you seen this new site? http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And also this http://aviation.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No I hadn't thank you. I tried glancing through them before I posted and didn't notice anything, but there are a lot now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote some Python scripts awhile back that pull from flight aware. You need to already know the airport or flight number.

https://github.com/khibma/FlightAwareRest

These calls cost $$$, so you need to make an account with them and provide a credit card (to obtain an api key). It's not real costly for a few flights, but I'm not sure how many you need to pull down.

You'd then have to perform some sort of average (conflation) yourself. (ArcGIS has these tools if you have it).

I'm sure others will provide free or cheaper alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [OpenFlights.org](http://openflights.org/).  Here you can download a lot of flight data for free.  In my experience, not all flight paths are in the database and some of them are seasonal, but it could give you a starting point.  To create geodesic flight lines from the airport points have a look at this [how-to discussion](http://anitagraser.com/2011/08/20/visualizing-global-connections/).

If you search this site, you'll find some other discussions that are related to this topic as well as how to create the lines.

Comment: Those paths appear to just be arcs across earth to connect two airports. If that is the case it is not accurate enough for what I need to do.